# Event fired on select box (html) being populated

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I've been wondering if browsers fire any event when select box is dynamicaly populated? I would expect 'onchange' being fired, but that doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been pointed out already, onchange event is responsible for User-made changes. However, when you change the DOM programmatically, the [DOM Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) is fired by some browsers, but that standard is not very well supported.

Answer (score 1):

[Mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) might be what you're looking for. They feature options like DOMSubtreeModified, DOMNodeInserted, and some others. Apparently there is a jQuery project on github to include support for Mutation-events. Check it out at http://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events/tree/master

Comment: You won't get mutation events in IE, certainly not up to and including version 7.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of.  For the most part, the only events that are dispatched are those initiated by the user.

A `<select>` receiving new options is technically initiated by the browser (even though it may happen as a result of a user action).

Although I agree that it would be particularly useful and cool if you *could* listen for changes on any arbitrary DOM property and bind handlers to react to those changes.

You can, however, look into a [signals and slots](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+signals+and+slots) implementation in javascript which might help you.